# Set a dynamic stride for tf.nn.conv2d layer

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, convolution

I want to pass a layer, say 9 x 1 through a kernel of size, say 2 x 1
Now what I want to do is convolve the following values together ->
1 and 2, 2 and 3, 4 and 5, 5 and 6, 7 and 8, 8 and 9
and then offcourse padd it.
What you can see from this example is that I am trying to make the stride in width dimension of the pattern ->
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, ...
and after every '1' I want to padd it so that finally the size doesnt change.

To simply see it I want to slice the main matrix into smaller matrices along a dimension, pass each of them separately through conv2d layers, padd them, and then concat them again along the same dimension but I want to do all this without actually cutting it up. I hope you understand what I am trying to ask. Is it possible?

Edit : Sorry should have mentioned this, I am using tensorflow libraries and I am talking about the tf.nn.conv2d function

Comment: Confusing question, your inputs are 1-d (9x1) and kernel is 1-d (2x1), you do a conv1-d, then it does [1,2] with kernel, [2,3] with kernel and so on, which is what you want? What is the 2-d convolutional and slicing a matrix all about?.

Comment: see the convolutions I want again.. maybe i wrote them in a confusing way sorry... i dont want [3, 4] and [6, 7].. make three groups.. [1,2,3] [4,5,6] [7,8,9].. i dont want any convolution that mixes anything from one group into other.. but in a particular group i want convolutional.. I hope you understand.. so the slicing I am talking about is slicing my 9 x 1 into three 3 x 1 s and work separately on them and than concatenate them back.. i was asking for an alternate to this